# On checkbox list how do I only display the next unchecked item?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes that are sorted in order of first item to the last item.  What I want to do is only display the next item not yet checked.  While I have 17 items now on the checklist, it may change up or down over time.

I have been playing with :nth-last-child, but I am unable to achieve what I want.

Here is an example of the HTML for the display of each checkbox item.

```html
<div class="my-check-col-12">...</div>
<div class="my-check-col-12">
  <span class="fa-stack" style="">
    <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x myc-text-type">
      ::before
    </i>
    <i class="fa-stack-1x fas fa-times myc-text-type">
    ::before
    </i>
  </span>
Item not complete</div>
<div class="my-check-col-12">...</div>
```

All help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: How are you keeping track of which checkboxes are checked?

Comment: What HTML/CSS are we talking about here? I don’t see any checkboxes in the HTML sense. What pre processor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

"Display next unchecked sibling checkbox when one is checked using JavaScript. Select with nextElementSibling and toggle a display class. Simple and keeps to-dos feel achievable one task at a time."

HTML:

```
<div class="my-check-col-12">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  <span class="fa-stack" style="">
    <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x myc-text-type"></i>
    <i class="fa-stack-1x fas fa-times myc-text-type"></i>
  </span>
  Item not complete
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Get all checkboxes and their parent divs
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.my-check-col-12');

// Find the next unchecked checkbox and display its corresponding item
function showNextUncheckedItem() {
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
      items[i].style.display = 'block';
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Call the function to display the next unchecked item
showNextUncheckedItem();
```

JavaScript can find the next unchecked checkbox and show its item when one is checked. It selects the next sibling, checks if unchecked, and toggles a display class to reveal only one item at a time. This helps tackle to-do lists piece by piece to stay motivated and keep large tasks feeling doable.

Comment: Where did the input element come from? It is not in the code given.